# Intercept HTTP Traffic of an android app?

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, wireshark, patch, http-proxy

I was trying to test and intercept traffic from an app developed on **Rhodes** open source framework, I setup a proxy with burp, and of course I have installed burp certificate on my device hence I can intercept other apps on my device but I am unable to see the traffic of the app in [question - its link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.path_solutions.premierbank&hl=en_US) on burp suite instead the app works fine and connects to the remote server without even appearing any error related to certificate error on the **event Log** of the burp suite just as like an app using **certificate Pinning** would complain. in reversing the [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.path_solutions.premierbank&hl=en_US) I concluded that it is using https protocol to connect to the server. additionally, I have installed the app in **Genymotion** emulator and the app behaves differently. when I installed the certificate in the emulator and set up burp proxy, all the traffic from other apps appears normally in the proxy except this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.path_solutions.premierbank&hl=en_US). all the app traffic follows to the address `127.0.0.1` which is strange to me. forexample I take an intercepted one below:

```
http://127.0.0.1:44895

POST /app/Settings/do_pathlogin HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:44895
Content-Length: 65
Accept: */*
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:44895
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; Samsung Galaxy S6 Build/OPR6.170623.017; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/58.0.3029.125 Mobile Safari/537.36
Transition-Enabled: true
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:44895/app/Settings/index_callback
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US
Connection: close

fromPage=login&operation_key=HOME_REP&username=user&password=pass
```

I don't have any idea why this behaviour the [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.path_solutions.premierbank&hl=en_US) is showing, in the real device this won't show up, i.e, traffic to the address `127.0.0.1`.
As other researchers would recommend, tried to sniff network traffic of the [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.path_solutions.premierbank&hl=en_US) with wireshark  and activated the capture traffic of the wireshark, I was expecting to sniff or even decide whether app is using UDP protocols, but did not appear any traffic from the app!.

**I wanted some help how can I capture the traffic of this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.path_solutions.premierbank&hl=en_US)?**

**what am I missing?**

**what other steps do I need?**

I would really appreciate any help about this.

**note: I don't have any bad intentions about the app.**

Comment: This doesn't seem programming related (i.e. the focus of Stack Overflow). You may want to ask this on our sister site, https://security.stackexchange.com/. This also seems like a bad question because it's so specific to your situation (both the app and the setup are unique to your question).

Comment: @RossJacobs thanks I'll share then though. although I saw a similar situations asked here on this site and get some answers. it is true that this is a bit specific

Comment: The more general you can make it, the easier it will be to help you (and the more people the q/a will in turn help). Can you reproduce the behavior with other apps? Can you reproduce this on a different computer?

Comment: in terms of generality, it is intercepting http traffic from an app, but what makes specific its apps framework. of course I didn't test any other app using the framework. yep I tested two different computers. it is still showing same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in looking at it, you need to address two things **firstly** the app is using a library which is non-proxy-aware to communicate to the server. **secondly** the app when sniffed with wireshark of course it encrypts its data so you need to extract the certificate from the app to view data in **wireshark**. but this is a tedious work but it is achievable. please do your homework. hope this answer will help.